# Reading strings from a text file

Tags: c#

So I'm basically trying to make simple login or register console app but I think I can't open the text file because everytime I enter the correct username it closes the app.This is the code which I think should work.

```
Console.WriteLine("Username:");
                string userNameN = Console.ReadLine();
                string username = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\test.txt");

            if (username == userNameN)

            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Correct username");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect username program will close");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

Comment: Debug your program, inspect the variables.

Comment: Use debugger... check the value of username and see what other characters are loaded as part of the string (new line). Also, use string.Equals(string1) to compare the values.

Comment: Besides using the debugger, you're likely to have whitespace and/or more than one line coming from your text file.  I would call `.Trim()` on both on your console input and the string coming from your text file.  Additionally, what if the cases doesn't match?  Consider adding `ToLower()` on both before performing your comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because execution of code is ended. If you want to wait till next input then add Console.ReadLine(); after Console.WriteLine("Correct username");

Now it will wait till next user input.